# What could multiple different BSODs mean?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bsod

My wife's (five-year-old) Win10 laptop has lately been having BSODs, with the only common factor that they happen:

- when she physically moves the laptop
- while it's turned on and the lid is open
- while it's on battery (i.e. not plugged-in)
- and only sometimes when all of the above are true.

The BSODs come up with different error messages. As an example, a couple of days ago the code was IRQL_NOT_GREATER_OR_EQUAL and today's was KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED. Her thought, from an engineering background, is possibly a short somewhere in her hardware that triggers sometimes when she moves it.

Could she be right, or is there a different explanation that may be able to be fixed through software fixes? Or is there something else at play entirely?

Comment: Usually means a bad stick of memory.

Comment: Thanks @Moab. I'm assuming that means a total replacement of the memory? We're not able to check each stick ourselves, and it's not worth the time and money trying to find a PC repair place in our town.